# Is it possible to generate a portable Scala JAR file with the Scala runtime embedded in it?

Tags: scala, jar, jvm, sbt, portability

Is it possible to create a Scala JAR file with all the required scala runtime classes included in it such that it would be possible to run on a default installation of the JVM?

So it should be executable by typing:

```
java -jar scala-app.jar
```

If this can be done using the Scala Build Tool that would be ideal but if it requires manually adding dependencies to the JAR file and editing the manifest file I can live with that.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: @Kolmar This looks ideal if it works as advertised.

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager is another option I guess

Comment: I got my answer so I am happy.